# With the Facebook API, can I figure out the user id of a user, given the username?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Long story short: if a user says that their username is "flyrev", how can I verify that that is the case?

I'm creating a database that will store links to Facebook profiles *by username*, so that I can easily say facebook.com/username.

For convenience, I thought I could use a simple Facebook login button, then after they logged in I could simply add facebook.com/that_user_id to the list if they click on "add me".

However, Facebook has removed the possibility of retrieving the username from the API. So, let's say I do it really awkwardly and *ask* the user for their Facebook profile link (which might seem weird to the user, but let's pretend I'm getting away with it UX wise).

Given that a logged in user gives me their username, can I match it against the ID to make sure that they provided the correct one?

Comment: You don’t need their username to be able to link to their profile. Just have them login to your app, and then request the `link` property of the user object - that gives you a URL that redirects to the correct profile address.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Facebook API is updated, I wrote this function to check the user's ID. Though it does not use the API, I hope it will help you!

```
<?php
function getUserId($username) {
  // Validate username
  if (preg_match('/[0-9.]{3,50}/', $username)) {
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://www.facebook.com/' . $username,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => FALSE,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36',
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 15,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 3,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($options);

    // Get ID from the response
    if ($http_code === 200 && strpos($response, '"entity_id"') !== FALSE) {
      if (preg_match('/"entity_id":"([0-9]+?)"/', $response, $regs)) {
        return $regs[1];
      }
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

For example:

[image: Get user ID from username]

Comment: Scraping Facebook is against their ToS. Plus, when they discover that you are doing this, you can easily get your server’s IP address blocked. This is not a recommendable solution at all.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the info!

Comment: The question quite clearly states that I want to do this through the API.